# Python Split Outputting in square brackets

Tags: python, string, expression

I have code that looks like this:

```
import re
activity = "Basketball - Girls 9th"
activity = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', activity).split('-')
activity = str(activity [1:2]) + str(activity [0:1])
print("".join(activity))
```

I want the output to look like `Girl's 9th Basketball`, but the current output when printed is
 `[' Girls 9th']['Basketball ']`
I want to get rid of the square brackets. I know I can simply trim it, but I would rather know how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. When you use `.join` on a `list` it creates a `string` so you can omit that step.

```
import re
activity = "Basketball - Girls 9th"
activity = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', activity).split('-')
activity = activity[1:2] + activity[0:1]
print(" ".join(activity))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are stringyfying the lists which is the same as using `print(someList)` - it is the representation of a list wich puts the [] around it.

```
import re
activity = "Basketball - Girls 9th"
activity = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', activity).split('-')
activity =  activity [1:2]  + [" "] +  activity [0:1] # reorders and reassignes list

print("".join(activity))
```

You could consider adding a step:

```
# remove empty list items and remove trailing/leading strings
cleaned = [x.strip() for x in activity if x.strip() != ""]

print(" ".join(cleaned)) # put a space between each list item
```

This just resorts the lists and adds the needed space item in between so you output fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in one line:

```
new_activity = ' '.join(activity.split(' - ')[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
activity = "Basketball - Girls 9th"
activity = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', activity).split('-')
activity = str(activity [1:2][0]).strip() + ' ' + str(activity [0:1][0])
print(activity)
```

output:

```
Girls 9th Basketball
```